# Maven install with maven-processor-plugin

Tags: java, maven, plugins

I have maven project with maven-processor-plugin
clean install - all work fine

Maven version 3.5.0

Local assembly is going well
But when I try to build an assembly on Jenkins I get an error

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.bsc.maven:maven-processor-plugin:3.3.1:process (process) on project model-core: Error executing: invalid flag: DBO -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.bsc.maven:maven-processor-plugin:3.3.1:process (process) on project model-core: Error executing
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:309)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:194)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:993)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:345)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:191)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Error executing
    at org.bsc.maven.plugin.processor.AbstractAnnotationProcessorMojo.execute(AbstractAnnotationProcessorMojo.java:429)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid flag: DBO
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTool.processOptions(JavacTool.java:206)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTool.getTask(JavacTool.java:156)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTool.getTask(JavacTool.java:107)
    at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTool.getTask(JavacTool.java:64)
    at org.bsc.maven.plugin.processor.AbstractAnnotationProcessorMojo.executeWithExceptionsHandled(AbstractAnnotationProcessorMojo.java:748)
    at org.bsc.maven.plugin.processor.AbstractAnnotationProcessorMojo.execute(AbstractAnnotationProcessorMojo.java:421)
    ... 22 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :model-core
Build step 'Вызвать цели Maven верхнего уровня  ' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

How can this be remedied?

Tried to run as root
The same mistake
http://storage1.static.itmages.ru/i/17/0809/h_1502290995_3373833_3b63b9c806.png

model-core

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>by.softclub.services.mobile</artifactId>
        <groupId>by.softclub.netteller.services</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>model-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
    <name>Model-Core</name>
    <packaging>ejb</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>by.softclub.netteller.services</groupId>
            <artifactId>by.softclub.banking.utils</artifactId>
            <version>${by.softclub.banking.utils.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>by.softclub.netteller.services</groupId>
            <artifactId>service-types</artifactId>
            <version>${service-types.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>by.softclub.netteller.services</groupId>
            <artifactId>printer</artifactId>
            <version>${printer.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-javaee-7.0</artifactId>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.unitils</groupId>
            <artifactId>unitils-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/java/</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.bsc.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-processor-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-processor-plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>process</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>process</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources</outputDirectory>
                            <processors>
                                <processor>com.querydsl.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                                <processor>org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.modelgen.CanonicalModelProcessor</processor>
                            </processors>
                            <compilerArguments>-Aeclipselink.persistencexml=${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml</compilerArguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
                        <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
                        <version>${querydsl-apt.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
                        <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen.processor</artifactId>
                        <version>${org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen.processor.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <forkMode>never</forkMode>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-ejb-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <filterDeploymentDescriptor>true</filterDeploymentDescriptor>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        </manifest>
                        <addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <implementation-version>${project.version}-r${buildNumber}</implementation-version>
                            <implementation-title>${project.build.finalName}</implementation-title>
                            <implementation-vendor>${user.name}</implementation-vendor>
                            <Dependencies>org.apache.cxf optional, org.apache.cxf.impl optional</Dependencies>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </archive>
                    <ejbVersion>${ejbVersion}</ejbVersion>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${buildnumber-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>create</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <doCheck>false</doCheck>
                    <doUpdate>true</doUpdate>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add your `pom.xml`.

Comment: Add the full command you used to run this build? Are you running via Maven Job Type in Jenkins or via pipeline step ?

Comment: My jenkins job http://storage7.static.itmages.ru/i/17/0810/h_1502353268_9371089_dbc6acbddf.png

Comment: The error concers java compiler and not the plugin. Probably the Jenkins job set some javac flags that are not compatible with compiler used by plugin.