# QueryDSL JPA metamodel

Tags: java, maven, jpa, querydsl, metamodel

Can you help me, how generate QueryDSL and JPA metamodel together.

I try

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
  <artifactId>querydsl-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>${querydsl.version}</version>  
  <executions>
    <execution>    
      <goals>
        <goal>jpa-export</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <targetFolder>target/generated-sources/java</targetFolder>
        <packages>
          <package>com.example.domain</package>
        </packages>
      </configuration>      
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

And

```
<plugin>
                            <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
                            <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>1.1.3</version>
                            <executions>
                                <execution>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>process</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                    <configuration>
                                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/meta-model</outputDirectory>
                                        <processor>org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.modelgen.CanonicalModelProcessor</processor>
                                        <processor>com.querydsl.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                                    </configuration>
                                </execution>
                            </executions>
                            <dependencies>
                                <dependency>
                                    <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
                                    <version>${querydsl-apt.version}</version>
                                </dependency>
                                <dependency>
                                    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen.processor</artifactId>
                                    <version>${org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen.processor.version}</version>
                                </dependency>
                            </dependencies>
                        </plugin>
```

But the project is not going to

I kind of found a solution, but I had a problem building it on Jenkins

```
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.bsc.maven</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-processor-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven-processor-plugin.version}</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>process</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>process</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                            <configuration>
                                <processors>
                                    <processor>com.querydsl.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                                    <processor>org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.modelgen.CanonicalModelProcessor</processor>
                                </processors>
                                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/meta-model</outputDirectory>
                                <compilerArguments>-Aeclipselink.persistencexml=${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml</compilerArguments>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
                            <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
                            <version>${querydsl-apt.version}</version>
                        </dependency>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
                            <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen.processor</artifactId>
                            <version>${org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen.processor.version}</version>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                </plugin>
```

[Maven install with maven-processor-plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45593124/maven-install-with-maven-processor-plugin?noredirect=1#comment78169522_45593124)

How to set up a project build. That there was a support for the metamodel JPA and QueryDSL ???

...
POM.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>by.softclub.services.mobile</artifactId>
        <groupId>by.softclub.netteller.services</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>model-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
    <name>Model-Core</name>
    <packaging>ejb</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>by.softclub.netteller.services</groupId>
            <artifactId>by.softclub.banking.utils</artifactId>
            <version>${by.softclub.banking.utils.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>by.softclub.netteller.services</groupId>
            <artifactId>service-types</artifactId>
            <version>${service-types.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>by.softclub.netteller.services</groupId>
            <artifactId>printer</artifactId>
            <version>${printer.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-javaee-7.0</artifactId>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.unitils</groupId>
            <artifactId>unitils-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/java/</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>

        <plugins>
            <!--
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                            <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>3.0.0</version>
                            <executions>
                                <execution>
                                    <id>add-source</id>
                                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>add-source</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                    <configuration>
                                        <sources>
                                            <source>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/annotations</source>
                                        </sources>
                                    </configuration>
                                </execution>
                            </executions>
                        </plugin>
            -->
            <!--
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>com.ethlo.persistence.tools</groupId>
                            <artifactId>eclipselink-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>2.6.4.2</version>
                            <executions>
                                <execution>
                                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>modelgen</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </execution>
                            </executions>
                        </plugin>
            -->
            <!--
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.bsc.maven</groupId>
                            <artifactId>maven-processor-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>${maven-processor-plugin.version}</version>
                            <executions>
                                <execution>
                                    <id>process</id>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>process</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                                    <configuration>
                                        <processors>
                                            <processor>com.querydsl.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                                            <processor>org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.modelgen.CanonicalModelProcessor</processor>
                                        </processors>
                                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/meta-model</outputDirectory>
                                        <compilerArguments>-Aeclipselink.persistencexml=${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml</compilerArguments>
                                    </configuration>
                                </execution>
                            </executions>
                            <dependencies>
                                <dependency>
                                    <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
                                    <version>${querydsl-apt.version}</version>
                                </dependency>
                                <dependency>
                                    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen.processor</artifactId>
                                    <version>${org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen.processor.version}</version>
                                </dependency>
                            </dependencies>
                        </plugin>
            -->
            <!--
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
                            <artifactId>querydsl-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>4.1.4</version>
                            <executions>
                                <execution>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>jpa-export</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                    <configuration>
                                        <targetFolder>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/meta-model</targetFolder>
                                        <packages>
                                            <package>by.softclub.model.entity</package>
                                        </packages>
                                    </configuration>
                                </execution>
                            </executions>
                        </plugin>
            -->
            <!--
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>add-source</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-source</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sources>
                                <source>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/meta-model</source>
                                <source>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/annotations</source>
                                <source>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/java</source>
                            </sources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            -->

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>process</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/meta-model</outputDirectory>
                            <processor>org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.modelgen.CanonicalModelProcessor</processor>
                            <processor>com.querydsl.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                            <processor>org.mapstruct.ap.MappingProcessor</processor>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
                        <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
                        <version>${querydsl-apt.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
                        <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen.processor</artifactId>
                        <version>${org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen.processor.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                        <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <forkMode>never</forkMode>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-ejb-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <filterDeploymentDescriptor>true</filterDeploymentDescriptor>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        </manifest>
                        <addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <implementation-version>${project.version}-r${buildNumber}</implementation-version>
                            <implementation-title>${project.build.finalName}</implementation-title>
                            <implementation-vendor>${user.name}</implementation-vendor>
                            <Dependencies>org.apache.cxf optional, org.apache.cxf.impl optional</Dependencies>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </archive>
                    <ejbVersion>${ejbVersion}</ejbVersion>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${buildnumber-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>create</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <doCheck>false</doCheck>
                    <doUpdate>true</doUpdate>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Also I try add

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
    <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen.processor</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

But have another errors

```
[ERROR] /E:/Server/V2_Change_Maven_Structure/by.services.mobile/model-core/src/main/java/by/model/dao/TransferLogDao.java:[103,50] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class QTransferLog
[ERROR]   location: class by.model.dao.TransferLogDao
```

**UPD 2**

When I use

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
    <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen.processor</artifactId>
</dependency>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>process</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/meta-model</outputDirectory>
                       <processor>com.querydsl.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
                    <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
                    <version>${querydsl-apt.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

All wokr fine. 
The project is going. But I can see

```
[INFO] --- apt-maven-plugin:1.1.3:process (default) @ model-core ---
E:\Server\V2_Change_Maven_Structure\by.services.mobile\model-core\src\main\java\by\softclub\model\dao\PushMessageStoreDao.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
import by.model.entity.PushMessageStore_;
                               ^
  symbol:   class PushMessageStore_
  location: package by.model.entity
E:\Server\V2_Change_Maven_Structure\by.services.mobile\model-core\src\main\java\by\softclub\model\dao\StreetTypeDao.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
import by.model.entity.StreetType_;
                               ^
  symbol:   class StreetType_
  location: package by.model.entity
E:\Server\V2_Change_Maven_Structure\by.services.mobile\model-core\src\main\java\by\softclub\model\dao\ImagesDAO.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
import by.model.entity.Images_;
                               ^
  symbol:   class Images_
  location: package by.model.entity
E:\Server\V2_Change_Maven_Structure\by.services.mobile\model-core\src\main\java\by\softclub\model\dao\UserDao.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
import by.model.entity.registration.Registration_;
                                            ^
  symbol:   class Registration_
  location: package by.model.entity.registration
E:\Server\V2_Change_Maven_Structure\by.services.mobile\model-core\src\main\java\by\softclub\model\dao\UserActionDao.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
import by.model.entity.UserAction_;
```

Comment: What version of java are you using? Annotation processors should be executed by the compiler and not require a separate plugin.

Comment: Java 8 I add my pom.xml

Comment: Does the `QTransferLog` class exist anywhere (normally generated-sources)?

Comment: NO =( I add some info also

Comment: You error seems to be related to the JPA metamodel not being generated. The pom.xml you posted doesn't make any reference to using java 8. The reason I'm insisting on checking if it's really java 8 (and I mean having the `maven-compiler-plugin` set to java 8, not just using jdk8) is because apt has been deprecated since jdk7 and javac should do annotation processing.
You're using JPA annotations, right?

Comment: My parent pom.xml             <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>windows-1251</encoding>
                    <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
                    <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

Comment: You're using JPA annotations, right? – 
What do you have in mind??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151699/discussion-between-kewne-and-lesharb).